# How to check the health of embedded tomcat in spring boot application?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, spring-boot, health-monitoring

Anyone know how to get information of incoming threads / queue size? I want to include it in health check (class extending AbstractHealthIndicator).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Actuator and Micrometer to get data about tomcat in spring boot. But if you want information about Thread you must configure more in spring boot config file.

`server.tomcat.mbeanregistry.enabled=true`